# Meaning of Const pointer C++ function call

Tags: c++, pointers

I Have a function in my code. This function have

```
const className * const * const varName
```

as its arguments. Can someone explain to me what does it means to have such a definition for a variable ?

Thanks

Comment: constant pointer to constant pointer to constant value

Comment: I missed part of it Can you see the correct command: const className * const * const varName